# Android how to keep values of login edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have login activity where username is read from `editText` field. How can I make such an functionality to suggest usernames that have been already logged in from the same device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `AutoCompleteTextView` instead of normal `EditText`

Save previous usernames in a sqlite db and then pull from that for the `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Here is some example code that should get you started.

```
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) 

findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_usernames);

String[] usernames = db.getUsernames();

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, usernames);

textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

For fast and easy implementation, you can use Android `SharedPreferences` in which you can easily save your previous input string.
[Read the documentation. It is well explained](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).

But if you want to save an array/arraylist, you can use also `SharedPreferences`.
[Read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences)